# Does the "/arch" switch of Visual C++ effect existing *static* libraries I link in?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Does the "/arch" switch of Visual C++ effect *static* libraries?

On the one hand, .lib files "classically" are supposed to contain finished object code that will just be linked into the EXE or DLL file. So the "/arch" switch clearly shouldn't have an effect on *existing* .lib files that I link in. I'd have to recompiled the .lib file inside it's own project/solution and change the "/arch" switch *there*.

But on the other hand, there is stuff like *link-time code generation* and *global optimization* nowadays, which means that the .lib actually only contains some kind of "intermediate" code now. And the actual code generation is deferred to the linker. This means the "/arch" switch might again effect even *existing* .lib files that I link in. So does it or does it not?

I could **not** find a definitive answer on this. So does anybody here know the specifics?

Regards,
MuldeR

Comment: Not certain, but I would say it's unlikely the normal .lib files you get with the compiler, or as part of third party code, are anything but "compiled to binary machine code for a specific process and ready to use" - the /arch only affects sources that are compiled into the project.

Comment: Well, I found a source that says this: _"Visual C++ .NET introduces **link-time code generation**. [...] The compiler front end doesn't invoke the back end. Instead, it emits an OBJ file with IL in it. [..] When the linker is invoked with IL-based OBJ files, it calls COM methods in the back end (C2.DLL) to generate the final, processor-specific code."_ And, after all, a static library (.lib) is nothing but a collection of OBJ files packed into an archive for re-use. So, where are the code generator settings taken from when a .lib is converted to the final machine code?

Comment: Right, so an object file can be either direct machine code or intermediate representation (IL). The point here is that there's a choice, when building the code, and I believe for example runtime libraries are built directly as machine code. It would probably be rather easy to find out by simply using the library extracting tool to extract one or a few of the object files in the library, and then run some decoding tool (dumpbin or similar) to see what the file actually contains. Since I only have Linux on all three of my home computers, I can't do that.

Comment: This is all a lot less sophisticated then you'd assume.  A static library is just a bag of .obj files, think of it as a .zip archive with no compression.  The compile options are embedded in the .obj file, you can see them with a hex viewer :)  Pretty handy actually when chasing a link problem induced by a wrong compiler option.  So nothing complicated going on here, the linker can easily run the compiler's back-end.

Comment: So, Hans, do you know what is in, for example, the runtime library? Object files with x86 machine code, or IL code that becomes x86 later on from the compiler backend?

Comment: Yes, I know a LIB file is pretty much an archive containing OBJ files. The _interesting_ case is when the LIB files contains OBJ files containing IL code rather than finished machine code. In this case the *linker* invokes the compiler back-end to convert the IL-based OBJ files that are contained in the LIB file into machine code. The big questions is: Where does the *linker* (or more specifically: the compiler back-end) take the compiler settings, like "/arch" from, in this case? So you are saying they are stored inside the LIB file for each OBJ and the project-specific settings are ignored?

Comment: Okay, so I compiled the same _static_ library two times, once with `/arch:SSE2` and once with `/arch:IA32`. Then I diff'ed the two resulting LIB files (see [**here**](http://i.imgur.com/Y7FM9nV.png)). There are a few more differences (maybe timestamps?), but indeed the compiler settings appear in the LIB file and they _differ_ between the two LIBs as expected. So you are probably right. Compiler settings, such as "/arch", are stored in the LIB file at the time of the LIB/OBJ file creation. The settings of the project that will use the LIB are probably **ignored**. That's good to know. Thanks!